# Is there anything that can mimic the apache module's mod_suexec behavior with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to have each virtual host ran as a different owner. I was told that in apache you can have mod_suexec configured to run each site folder as the owner of the folder. Is there anything that can do something like that or something even close for nginx?

I'm running Arch Linux with NginX 1.0.15.

Comment: You can use PHP-FPM for PHP processing from different users. But for non-PHP, I'm not sure of the options--researching this myself, so I'll watch this question.

Comment: I am surprised that nothing of this equivalent is out there, that I know of. You would think that with all the web severs out there, this issue has to come up.

Answer (score 1):

I'll copy answer from [nginx FAQ](http://wiki.nginx.org/Faq#What_about_support_for_something_like_mod_suexec.3F):

> What about support for something like mod_suexec?
>
> mod_suexec is a solution to a problem that Nginx does not have. When running servers such as Apache, each instance consumes a significant amount of RAM, so it becomes important to only have a monolithic instance that handles all one's needs. With Nginx, the memory and CPU utilization is so low that running dozens of instances of it is not an issue.
>
> A comparable Nginx setup to Apache + mod_suexec is to run a separate instance of Nginx as the CGI script user (i.e. the user that would have been specified as suexec user under Apache), and then proxy to that from the main Nginx instance.
>
> Alternatively, PHP could simply be executed through FastCGI, which itself would be running under a CGI script user account. (Note that mod_php - the module suexec is normally utilized to defend against - does not exist with Nginx.)